# Is duplication okay in random forest modelling?

Tags: sas, random-forest, decision-tree

I am using random forest modelling for a project. The tool used is SAS Eguide.
My data is 12 months history with a moving payment history. Below table summarizes my data.

| acc | payment_3months | dueamt_3mons | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2314 | 100 | 200 | 01 |
| 2314 | 300 | 200 | 02 |
| 3241 | 450 | 450 | 01 |
| 3241 | 500 | 500 | 02 |
| 3241 | 250 | 350 | 03 |

Does this data looks okay to be fed in the random forest? Or should I aggregate these data and remove duplicates and keep single row for each acc value?
Please advice

Comment: What are you trying to predict?

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for [stats.se], as this isn't a programming question, but a statistical one.  Please read the [faq] and the [help] both here and on [stats.se] for more information on what's on topic at each site and what a good question looks like.  Thanks!!